# Electron python shell vs sockets

Tags: python, electron

What I have is electron app that runs the frontend and python app that runs in backend. At some point I need to execute python script and get info from it.

I'm currently using [python shell for node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) (communicate through standard I/O), however I was able to find [another method with sockets](https://github.com/fyears/electron-python-example). What are the advantages of using sockets compared to standard I/O? From what I understand, I can only pass strings either way. Which performs better?